# ArcGIS -ArcMap Advanced SQL Expression Returning Blank Output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, sql

[image]

Want to return the comments that only show "Pending Annexation - Pending City Limits", but is returning a blank value.

Comment: I'm not great with VBScript, but with python you need to return your desired value from your function like: return FindLabel.

Comment: Verify button, as far as I know, applies your expression to the very first record and if your expression is not applicable to this first row, it return an empty string. To test the idea try filling out else part, say `FindLabel = "No label to show"`.